# How is the inventory of a spouse's shop determined?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Since I married Mjoll the Lioness recently she's set up shop in my home and it seems like the merchandise she sells varies greatly depending her current location/actual inventory. I traded her things like dragon scales/materials and checked her shop to find those materials listed there as well.

If this is the case, I guess my real question is are the items that are listed in her store ***my*** items? and will they ever be sold or "disappear" somehow without my consent or knowledge? I really don't want to find out that valuable items/weapons/armor I spent a long time acquiring ended up being the "deal of the week."

Are items in my spouse's shop mine and will they ever be sold against my will?

Comment: Owned chests, like the one(s) in your home(s), are a much better way of storing items you might want later.

Comment: i married her as well, but im having a slight problem. the first time i checked her store, she carried everything. but afterwards a traded her a suit of plate steel armor for her to wear, and she put it on, but now she has no items in her store other than her old iron armor and no money at all. im so lost on what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your spouse was a merchant before you married them, they will sell the same goods they would normally. If not, they will sell pawnbroker-type goods and (reportedly) loose items you leave in their inventory. They will not sell items you leave around the house.

Their inventory "refreshes" like other shopkeeper inventories, so don't sell them something you are planning to buy back later.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. looks like I'll have to make sure I sell any loot I put on them before I do anything else.

Answer (score -1):

From wiki: "You don't need to worry about losing items by placing them in your spouse's inventory because they sold them to someone. Like all merchants in the game, they will actually only sell things to you, and not other people."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you include a link to the page on the wiki you quoted this from? You can add it by editing your post by clicking the "edit" button in the bottom left corner of your post.