# Why items such as leather strips keep disappearing from my chests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

In The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, with the Hearthfire DLC, my items, such as leather strips, keep disappearing from chests in my Falkreath home. This is very annoying.

My wife Ysolda lives in this house. She keeps selling me my own stuff for 100+ gold each. I can't kill her.

Why are my items disappearing?

Comment: Where are these chests? In your marital house? Which house is that?

Comment: Yes they are in my house on the property in falkreath

Comment: Who is your spouse? After a little research (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37587/how-is-the-inventory-of-a-spouses-shop-determined, https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/483368526573218533/, http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Marriage/Archive_4#Spouses_Taking_Stored_Items) it sounds like whether the spouse was a trader or not before may affect how they acquire their items.

Comment: Ysolda from whiterun.

Comment: I all noticed you play fallout 4 so I had a question

Comment: If you have a question about Fallout 4, post it as a question. I'll certainly look at it, and so will other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found references to others having this same issue: ([1](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/483368526573218533/), [2](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Marriage/Archive_4#Spouses_Taking_Stored_Items)). It doesn't match the [designed behavior](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37587/108003) reported by most of the people that play the game, and therefore appears to be a bug. It seems to only affect Xbox players.

There's no known solution or cause. It seems that you simply need to store your items somewhere else so that your greedy wife can't get to them.

**Set up a man-cave.**

You need to put your stuff in safe locations or containers. These are places that don't respawn, meaning that your stuff will still be there when you get back.

This includes houses you've bought such as your marital home, obviously, but also quite a few other places. I put the [list in another answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/272412/108003), and there's also [a whole question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35314/108003) devoted to the subject.

Comment: OK thank you a lot I invested in the 10 safes in the celler of my house and everything's safe

Comment: @EverettMatthews No problem. Sorry I couldn't provide a real solution. If you find an answer useful, don't forget to upvote.